# Background Location Flutter Plugin fails when running flutter build apk

Tags: android, flutter

Trying to build an Android APK for the background_location Flutter Plugin. For some reason it gives the below errors. The application runs on the ios emulator.

Plugin Link: https://pub.dev/packages/background_location/example

```
e: /Users/my-cpu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/background_location-0.8.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/almoullim/background_location/BackgroundLocationService.kt: (23, 1): Class 'BackgroundLocationService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: /Users/my-cpu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/background_location-0.8.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/almoullim/background_location/BackgroundLocationService.kt: (221, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':background_location:compileReleaseKotlin'.
```

Comment: Have you added all the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Seems the issue has a fix. It's discussed here: https://github.com/Almoullim/background_location/issues/150

Comment: Have your issue resolved or not?

Comment: Yes. There is an explanation on the link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

in BackgroundLocationService.kt replace

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array?, grantResults: IntArray?): Boolean
```

with

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array, grantResults: IntArray): Boolean
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).